# Clear display of LaTeX errors and warnings in texstudio?

Tags: errors, texstudio, warnings

I have a question about using TeXstudio, how to clear display of LaTeX *errors* and *warnings* in texstudio?
[image]
I copied the image from TeXstudio github webpage, and found out about this feature, but I don't know how to achieve this. It will be highly appreciated if anybody can shed some light regarding this.

Comment: I suspect you are misunderstanding "clear" here. In doesn't mean "empty" the display but more in the sense of "good display of errors".

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I think you're right, I must have misunderstood the meaning here. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Anyway, so how to empty those disturbing errors when there have a lot of errors after compiling?

Comment: I don't use texstudio, but I would say that way to get rid of them is to correct the document.

Comment: @Jiapan (Un-)Show log markers: https://imgur.com/a/qumIY (for un-highlighting errors in the document), and (Un-)Show Error/Warning/Bad box (the 3 symbols to its left) for un-showing errors in the "issues" window. This is temporary though, they show up again after recompilation if the errors are still present.

Answer (score 2):

I think they intend that with `View > View > Messages / Log file` (I'm not sure about the names because I have the Italian version) you can see a list of the errors, other than the complete log:

[image]

and if you pass the mouse on the "no trespassing" sign near the wrong instruction, you can see the error description also there:

[image]

<sup>If the display doesn't look familiar to you, take into account I have a dark theme.</sup>